# GridView without scrolling

Tags: android

I'd like to create a layout width GridView that takes the whole screen (fill_parent for both width and height).
Number of columns is X, number of rows is Y (filled with own adapter, extending BaseAdapter).
What I don't want is scrolling. I'd like to have all items visible, no vertical scroll bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following `OnTouchListener`:

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

set attribute android:scrollingCache="false" in your GridView

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scrollingCache="false"
   android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

..maybe:

```
mKeypadGrid.setEnabled(false);
```

will solve your problem. It disabled scroll but other functionality I need was working. Not sure if it will fit to your needs.. Cheers